# R Shiny - parametrize variable names

Tags: r, shiny

I need to parametrize variable names associated to existing variables.

For example:

I have n existing Shiny inputs:

```
input$input1, ..., input$inputn
```

How can I use those variables in a loop?

```
listOfEl <- list()

for(i in 1:n){
    listOfEl[[i]] <- input$input n°i # what's the right R syntax for  'input$input n°i' ?
}
```

Comment: `input` is already a list, so you probably dont need `listOfEl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
eval(parse(text = paste("input$input",i,sep="")))
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly the expression I was looking for!